# Implicit deallocation

Tags: c

In a program, if a variable is declared it allocates space and at the end of the program deallocates space in case of dynamic memory allocation. I know that it allocates space in a heap, but my question is: Why can't the compiler implicitly deallocate memory in heap?

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking. In general: maybe you allocated that memory for a reason. The compiler cant decide if you *forgot* to de-alloctate, or if you left it there for a reason.

Comment: Compiler does not allocate or deallocate any memory. It only translates the source code into a machine code. Compiler even does not know anything about functions which you use to allocate and deallocate the memory.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 that's not necessarily true, many compilers **do** know about the semantics of standard functions and use that to apply additional checks, optimize the code, and so on. But you could say the compiler doesn't **need** to know anything about any functions.

Comment: @Felix Palmen yes but it does not matter in this question. many compilers have malloc etc built in but the actual implementation depends on the target system. Even those ones usually do not provide any deallocation (at least I have not seen any) in the program epilogue routines (which are external pieces of code anyway) and leave in the best case for the hosting system (if any).

Comment: @PeterJ_01 I didn't say it was relevant for the question, it's just not entirely correct. See for example [gcc's malloc attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes).

Comment: @Felix Palmen IMO you dive too deep into the problem considering the level of the question. IMO the answer is - **deallocate what you have allocated. Do not try to cut the corners,** .

Comment: @PeterJ_01 I just provide a complete explanation. Whether it helps the OP depends on his willingness to learn and look up further resources based on my answer.

Comment: This is handled by the OS, not by the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

> Why can't the compiler implicitly deallocate memory in heap

Because it doesn't know / cannot tell if something else might still need to access the heap node.

What you are talking about here is *garbage collection*.  The type system for C is not strong enough to implement (non-conservative) garbage collection.

And note that even in a garbage collected language, it is rarely the compiler that decides whether / when to deallocate a dynamically allocated heap node.

Comment: It bears mentioning explicitly that a compiler *can* potentially decide whether to deallocate objects given an appropriate type system, although whether this counts as GC depends largely on your definitions (often marketed as "no GC needed!"). As you do say, C doesn't have such a type system.

Comment: Such languages (like Rust) come with limitations on what you can do with them and / or a different way of thinking about memory management lifetimes.

Comment: For example, in Rust an application will need to explicitly break cycles in a cyclic data structure to get it to be reclaimed.  (There is no free lunch when it comes to cycles in graphs!)

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about *dynamic memory allocation*, which means creating the object with `malloc()` and friends. In this case, many implementations use something like the "*heap*" the operating system provides. Such an operating system typically performs the necessary cleanup on exit.

But **be aware** C doesn't know anything about this. C only specifies that there's a thing called an allocated object which has *dynamic storage duration*, and this means it stays alive **until** you call `free()`. As C is designed in a way so it can be implemented virtually anywhere, it doesn't even need an *operating system*. So, while omitting `free()` works on your typical PC and the like, this code could cause problems on some platform where there's nothing in place to "clean up after you". You can even run into problems in a *long running* program as your allocated objects might accumulate to an ever growing amount when you never call `free()`, this is calles a *memory leak*.

That said, C *includes* a simple concept of implicit deallocation: Objects with *automatic storage duration*. They are released as soon as the execution leaves their enclosing scope. Any variable you declare inside a function has by default *automatic storage duration*.

Also note that a lot of newer languages don't require you to explicitly manage memory for your dynamically allocated objects. This only works because they come with some *runtime code* that includes a *garbage collector*. So your program written in these languages needs additional code that's for example linked to it (or that's part of a virtual machine executing your code, like it's the case in e.g. Java). C doesn't include such a thing, but there are garbage collectors available for C you could use *explicitly*. You could have a look at [Boehm GC](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/) if you're interested in this.

Answer (score 0):

This would imply that the compiler had to alter the semantics of your program, which is outside of what a compiler should do in the first place.

There are several imaginable circumstances where you would want to not deallocate heap memory, for performance or other reasons.

Garbage collection, as some refer to in their answers, relies on a runtime system keeping track of your memory regions and their references, but such a runtime does not exist in C.

Answer (score 0):

A compiler can't do that because it is a runtime decision. You cannot know when to deallocate without executing the program.

This is what is done in garbage collection systems.

What about this piece of code:

```
int* p[1000000];
for (i= 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
   p[i]= malloc(1000000);

   // Initialize this block
}

for (i= 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
   if (Condition(i))
   {
     // Process this block
   }
}
```

Comment: Better use C examples in a question tagged C.

Comment: Unfortunately `new` does not exist in the C language.

Comment: Does this deserve a downvote ? The language is actually irrelevant.

Comment: @YvesDaoust although not my DV, I still think yes, it does. You could as well answer with a bit of Java if the language **was** irrelevant :o

Comment: @YvesDaoust of course it will, you can't expect someone asking about C to know what `new` is supposed to mean! And btw, I don't understand what you try to express with this code snippet ... care to explain?

Comment: @Yves Daoust : `you know very well that C and C++ won't make any difference` it is at least a disputable statement.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: without explicit deallocation, the program cannot run as it will try to allocate a terabyte. Though in reality, maybe all blocks can be deallocated in the first loop, depending on the condition, you don't know.

Comment: @Yves Daoust it was actually about you

Answer (score 0):

The compiler just translates your C code to machine code. It doesn't "know" how long an allocated memory block is accessed in the program code, because it doesn't run the code. To allow automatic deallocation, a special runtime facility is needed that tracks references to objects on the heap - like the garbage collectors used in languages like C# and JavaScript. However, those garbage collectors usually don't deallocate memory immediately, but wait until they run low on memory. Then they will dispose of all unused "garbage" memory they've detected so far.